# End to end testing of password reset functionality

Tags: spring, testing, junit

I'm writing core service for a small system. There is a usecase where user can request password reset. This means that random value is sent to him via email. I want to test whole flow of this case (except for sending and reading email), but I'd have to leak this value from the core and I can't do it.

It seems that the only way to do it properly is to create a `@Component` with single method, something like `getRandomString()` and mock it. But it seems a little excessive. Is there a better way to do it?

**Edit:** what I want to test is not whether mail contains proper number. Resetting passwords works like this: user provides email, some randomly generated number (in fact a pretty long token is returned, but idea stays the same) is generated and sent to this email, after that this token must be entered on some page (by clicking provided link, copying and pasting, whatever, common procedure) along with new password. My code checks whether there we know this token and if yes, we change user's password to the new one. I want to test this whole process in a single method annotated with `@Test` - sending and receiving email will be mocked, and I think this is where I can get this value.

Comment: Can you share some code so we have a frame of reference here?

Comment: Perhaps, in this case, a question would be "why is the number important"? What do you want to test? That a mail with a text that contains a random number goes out. Can't you simply test that without knowing the random number, for example by testing the mail text against a regex? Is it actually required that you KNOW which number comes out or do you just need to check THAT a number comes out?

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz I have edited my question to address  your questions.

Comment: Are you using any framework for testing? With JMockit for example you could mock this Random method to return whatever you want.

Comment: I'm using Mockito, but the problem is not whether I can mock it or not, it's more about HOW to do it. Random value is generated deep in my code and I'd like to know how should I mock it. Of course, as I wrote in an edit, I can simply provide fake implementation of mailin service and store this value for later retrieval. In this case this is possible, but this won't be always true.

Comment: You can use [powermockito to mock Random](https://gist.github.com/kribblo/3424710) and return the value that you'd expect

Comment: Wow, someone else can change the title of my question? That's neat, but I don't think new title is what this question is about. In fact my question was answered by Morific in the comment above. Unfortunately it's not an answer so I can't rate it.

Comment: Yes, you can mock static methods, I just don't see why you should - and it tends to bring more problems than it solves. Why can't you test it by starting the reset-process, mock the email sending, retrieving the url from the mocked email, use that url to test the reset-function and then check if the password was reset correctly? No need to actually determine what the random number will be...

Comment: Quite probably this is what I will do, I even wrote it in an edit. Never the less I'm still interested in others approach to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There have been some good suggestions in the comments section. Thus, I'd separate at least the following aspects:

**1)** Implementing you scenario:

*Florian Schaetz's* point of view is spot on, go for the simplest solution possible. Unless you absolutely need a specific value from its content, just use the generated URL and you're done.

*Raedwald* has a healthy suggestion as well. Having to verify multiple things inside a test is usually an indication that it should be split into several parts to check each of the corresponding functionality, otherwise you'll end up building a *[god object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object)*

**2)** Strictly regarding mocking:

Mockito has [a few limitations](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/FAQ) which most of the time can be overcome in combination with [powermock](https://github.com/jayway/powermock). For your integration test you should be able to [mock the creation of your random class](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage#how-to-mock-construction-of-new-objects) so you'll have control over what it returns:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) // delegate test running to Powermock so it can work its magic
@PrepareForTest({RandomMockeryTest.ClassUsingRandom.class}) // define classes which powermock should manipulate 
public class RandomMockeryTest {

    private Random mockedRandom;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        // mock Random
        mockedRandom = PowerMockito.mock(Random.class);

        // make it return 100, waaay bigger than 10, isn't it?!
        PowerMockito.doReturn(100).when(mockedRandom).nextInt(Mockito.anyInt());

        // whenever a new Random instance is created, make sure to return our mock
        PowerMockito.whenNew(Random.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(mockedRandom);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSomethingRandom() {
        // instantiate the class under test
        ClassUsingRandom classUsingRandom = new ClassUsingRandom();

        // call the method and make sure it returns the expected value
        assertEquals(100, classUsingRandom.giveMeARandomValue());
    }

    public static class ClassUsingRandom {
        public int giveMeARandomValue() {
            // this should return an int between 0 and 10, not even close to 100
            return new Random().nextInt(10);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to test the full functionality end to end. Use low level tests to test the low level components function correctly. Then use a few higher level (integration) end to end tests to check that the low level components are correctly connected to each other.

Comment: This certainly answers question with current title, yet it doesn't answer my original question, since I weren't asking about testing whole functionalilty, I've been basically asking about approach to the problem of mocking random number generator used deeper inside code.